# Symfony2 Form Option Resolution

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig, fosuserbundle

I'm using the **FOSUserBundle** and I'm trying to customize a user registration form with an **is_admin option**. I'm at a loss as to why the option value is not passed from the `createForm()` function call to the `buildForm()` function.

Below is the corresponding code in the controller:

```
$has_admin_rights = $this->get('security.authorization_checker')
->isGranted('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN');
/** @var $formFactory \FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FactoryInterface */
$formFactory = $this->get('fos_user.registration.form.factory');
/** @var $userManager \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface */
$userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
$user = $userManager->createUser();
...
$form = $formFactory->createForm(
new RegistrationFormType(), $user, array('is_admin' => $has_admin_rights));
```

Below is the custom form class which should, in theory, resolve the **is_admin** option. However it seems like the option is not properly passed.

```
class RegistrationFormType extends AbstractType
{
      public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    if($options['is_admin'] === true)
    {
        $builder->add('uniqueRole', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => array('ROLE_ADMIN' => 'user.role.admin',
                'ROLE_TEACHER' => 'user.role.teacher',
                'ROLE_STUDENT' => 'user.role.student'),
            'label' => 'form.label.role',
            'expanded' => false,
            'multiple' => false,
            'mapped' => false
            ));
        $builder->remove('plainPassword')->add('plainPassword', 'hidden', array('data' => 'defaultPwd'));
    } else {
        // Default value is indeed set, 
        // and options[is_admin] always equals to false
        if (array_key_exists("is_admin", $options)){
            echo 'Set!';
        } else {
            echo 'Not Set!';
        }
    }
    $builder->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'actions.add'));
}

protected function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setRequired(array(
        'is_admin'));
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'is_admin' => false,
        'data_class' => 'VMB\UserBundle\Entity\User',
        'intention'  => 'registration',
    ));
}

// BC for SF < 2.7
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $this->configureOptions($resolver);
}

public function getParent()
{
    return 'fos_user_registration';
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'vmb_user_registration';
}
}
```

I've also tried passing the parameter to a constructor this way

`$form = $formFactory->createForm(new RegistrationFormType($has_admin_rights), $user);`

however the symfony2 appCache initializes the form object without the proper param value (which falls back to defined `null` default value).
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am curious... `$formFactory` is actually which type? I cannot find method named `createForm` in either `FormFactory`, `FormFactoryBuilder` or `FormFactoryInterface`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's just a matter of invoking the wrong service.

You obtained the instance of `FormFactory` through:

```
$formFactory = $this->get('fos_user.registration.form.factory');
```

but this is not Symfony's `FormFactory`. In the matter of fact if you look at it's source [**here**](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Form/Factory/FormFactory.php), you will see this:

```
public function createForm()
{
    return $this->formFactory->createNamed($this->name, $this->type, null, array('validation_groups' => $this->validationGroups));
}
```

Basically, `createForm` does not expect any arguments at all.

So, instead, you should use Symfony's own `form.factory` ([source](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Form/Factory/FormFactory.php)):

```
$has_admin_rights = $this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN');

/** @var $formFactory \FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FactoryInterface */
$formFactory = $this->get('form.factory');

/** @var $userManager \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface */
$userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');

$user = $userManager->createUser();

$form = $formFactory
    ->createBuilder(new RegistrationFormType(), $user, array('is_admin' => $has_admin_rights))
    ->getForm();
```

Hope this helps...